# Show duplicate records for a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to see the duplicate records for an object over a week period.  I am interested in  seeing the duplicates, not objects that have had only a single instance.  This is what I have written so far:

```
SELECT a.asset, t.ticketnum, t.symptom_mask, t.setsolution, t.`otherdesc`
    FROM lamarinfo AS a
    JOIN lfso AS t
    ON (a.id = t.asset_id)
    WHERE open_dt BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND SYSDATE()
GROUP BY a.`asset` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This returns the records that are duplicate, but not each record for the duplicates.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right so you should be able to handle this with a subquery.

```
SELECT a.asset, t.ticketnum, t.symptom_mask, t.setsolution, t.`otherdesc`
   FROM lamarinfo AS a
   JOIN lfso AS t
   ON (a.id = t.asset_id)
   WHERE a.asset IN (SELECT asset FROM lamarinfo WHERE open_dt BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND SYSDATE() GROUP BY asset HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```